# Deployment stops after creation of few resources

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

I am instantiating a deployment from Helm. a few pods are getting created but the deployment stops right after creating few pods. Although I cannot share much info on the deployment as it is related to my company, how can I debug this kind of issue?  The created pods have no problem as seen from logs and events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to debug your application you should first of all :

- Check the pods logs using `sh kubectl logs pod <pod-name>`
- check the event using  `sh kubectl get events .....`

Sometimes if a pods crush you can find the logs or events so you need to add a flag to logs command :
`sh kubectl logs pods <pod-name> --previous=true`

I hope that can help you to resolve your issue.